# Questions on how the build .c files

Tags: android

I have been trying to implement the API for the serial port found the the below web page.  I am a beginner in all this and I am sure about what I am looking at:

http://code.google.com/p/android-serialport-api/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fandroid-serialport-api%2Fproject%2Fjni

Questions:

1) The .c files are built how?  Do I need to download the NDK?  I assume the .c file is run directly by the virtual machine, or what?  Or is the executable for the .c the file in the libs directory?  If so, how do I utilize the libserial_por.so file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .c files are built into a library by running `ndk-build` in the project directory. You need the NDK.

The .c files are not run directly by the virtual machine, but rather a library is created in the `libs` directory, which is then loaded along with the `SerialPort` class.

To use the library, just use the `SerialPort` class which already has bindings to the library.

---

C files will be compiled to an ARM binary library with the extension .so by the NDK. Take a look at the [NDK Documentation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html), section "Getting Started with the NDK", to find out how to use it.

Basically, you place your .c files in the `jni` directory, change `Android.mk` to specify how to compile them, then run `ndk-build` to build the library. The resulting `lib<name>.so` will be placed in the `lib` directory. You then use your library in the Java project with `System.loadLibrary('<name>')`.

This of course means the library must have a JNI interface for you to be able to use with the Java application, since Android doesn't support JNA yet.

I see though that the code you pointed out is an Android project. To run it, simply run `ndk-build` in the project directory to build the library, then run the project in an emulator.

Comment: Thanks.  So the file in the lib directory is the result of the .c build.  That means that I already have the .so file I need.  Good.

Comment: If you already have it, then it's OK, you don't need to rebuild it.

Comment: So if I just leave the .so file in the lib directory and start Eclipse, it will find the library (the .so file) in the lib directory? Or do I have to do something special to tell it that the .so file is there?

Comment: Eclipse shouldn't care about the library, or know what to do with it. It will package it in the .apk though, and it should work in the emulator without you doing anything extra.